# How to bold a specific word(a passed parameter) in passed textparagraph

Tags: angularjs, regex

I want to bold a specific word (which is a passed parameter) in another passed parameter which is a text paragraph.

So over all what I am doing is : 
- search the word lets say "help" in the paragraph " I am stuck , please help me"
- and when this word "help" is found in the paragraph then replace it with  **help**  so that the paragraph changes to " I am stuck , please **help** me" . I have been trying regex expressions to do but unable to figure out the problem.

**Html code:**

```
<div>
      {{ boldText(value.search_keywords, value.url.textRecieved) }}
</div>
```

**AngularJS code:**

```
$scope.boldText=function(searchKeywordsList, textParagraph){
        var final_textParagraph;
        for (var index=0; index<searchKeywordsList.length; index++){
            if (textParagraph.indexOf(searchKeywordsList[index]) > -1) {
                var regex = new RegExp('\\*(.+?)\\*', 'g');
                var replace = '<b>$1</b>';
                var searchedKeyword = searchKeywordsList[index].replace(searchKeywordsList[index], '*'+searchKeywordsList[index]+'*');
               /* console.log(searchedKeyword);*/
                var boldValue = searchedKeyword.replace(regex, replace);
                console.log(boldValue);
                final_textParagraph = textParagraph.replace(searchKeywordsList[index], boldValue);
            }
            else{
                final_textParagraph = textParagraph;
            }
        }
        return final_textParagraph;
    };
```

**Current Output:**

- Search for Keywords:

revenue,
network

- Website Data:

...security) and most recently served as VP of Worldwide Sales at Shape Security. Prior to that Rotolo served as VP of Sales - West at Palo Alto Networks, where he helped grow revenues from zero to over $350 million per year.

**Expected Output:**

- Search for Keywords:

revenue,
network

- Website Data:

...security) and most recently served as VP of Worldwide Sales at Shape Security. Prior to that Rotolo served as VP of Sales - West at Palo Alto **Network**s, where he helped grow **revenue**s from zero to over $350 million per year.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include ngSanitize and use ng-bind-html if you want to inject markup like that. And also please dont use `<b>` element, but instead apply a span with a bold style like `<span class="bold"></span>`

The usage is

```
<ANY
  ng-bind-html="">
...
</ANY>
```

In your case

```
<div ng-bind-html="boldText(value.search_keywords, value.url.textRecieved)"></div>
```

Make sure to include ngSanitize
Read more about ng-bind-html: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml