# Angular - Bold Search Term in Results ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a company search page where I pass in the search term "test" and it returns an array of objects

```
[{CompanyName: 'Test Company', Description: 'This is a test description.'}]
```

I have an ng-repeat that displays these in a table

```
<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
  <td>{{company.CompanyName}}</td>
  <td>{{company.Description}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I want to bold the search term in each of the results.

```
<b>Test</b> Company | This is a <b>test</b> description.
```

But the only posts I can find on this have to do with filtering which I don't want to do. I assume I have to use a directive, but the specifics are what allude me here. I can't seem to put all the pieces together to make this work the way I want. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks! -Jim

Comment: Why do you not want to do filtering?

Comment: @JimAdkins Did you look at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134189/angularjs-how-to-bold-a-specific-worda-passed-parameter-in-passed-textparagr

Comment: @kanchirk, thanks. I'll play with that and see if I can get it to work.
NewDev becuase my search has already filtered out records, and I just want to display the results with some bolded text, not filter within the results.

Comment: @JimAdkins, the filtering that I'm sure these posts or blogs refer to is the filter that takes text and outputs HTML with the appropriately bolded words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @kanchirk, I've figured it out. I'm still new to angular, but with your suggested post I got it. What I had read is that I had to pass in $sce as a "dependency injection," but I thought passing it as a variable in the function was doing that. Once I figured that out how wrong I was, it worked like a charm.

```
    .controller("SearchCtrl", ['$scope', '$sce', 
        function ($scope, $sce) {    
            $scope.boldText = function (text) {
                var htmlText;
                var regex = RegExp($scope.textField, 'gi')
                var replacement = '<strong>$&</strong>';
                htmlText = $sce.trustAsHtml(text.replace(regex, replacement));
                return htmlText;
            };
     }]);
```

Along with:

```
<span ng-bind-html="boldText(company.Keywords)"></span>
```

Thanks to all for their help and suggestions. I really appreciate it.